# How do I mimic the background color of this table view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Apple ships an app named “Contacts” on every iOS device. On the iPhone and iPod touch, it has a very particular way of styling the area above the search bar:

[image]

**How is this coloring accomplished?** Specifically, how is the color only visible at the top of the table view, and not at the bottom? Setting the `backgroundColor` property of the table view or its `backgroundView` does not achieve the desired result, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just create a `UIView` with gray `backgroundColor` containing a `UISearchBar` at the bottom of it, and set that to the [`tableHeaderView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView) of your `UITableView`.

Comment: What he said. Views are not clipped by default on iOS, so if you make a header view that is about 40px high and into that you insert a grey subview behind your search bar that is 200px high, when you drag the header down, you will see the grey subview ascending above the view boundary. That should create the effect you want.

Comment: @NickLockwood Thanks, that seems to be the consensus. ;) http://c.abr.vg/DQmK http://c.abr.vg/DQQL

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's another view in a UIScrollView? (If so, above contentOffset.)